# how to make the user have the correct input type in c

Tags: c

I just started learning c programming, my question might be so silly.

I try to create a function to grab user input using scanf(). before that, I will have the menu displayed, and the user should only enter a number. so there is my question, how can I check whether the user enters an integer or character string or any other symbol. and send an error message if they do so?

Comment: You must always check the value returned by the function, which is how many successful conversions were made. So if you have `int res = scanf("%d", &value)` then if `res != 1` the input was unsuccessful. Always check for the *specific* number of conversions required. You see code that tests `res` with `0` and with `EOF` but they are not great practice. You can see that with the example `res = scanf("%d%d", &val1, &val2);` Here testing against `0` or `EOF` is actually wrong, when just 1 conversion was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to [scanf() manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=functions-scanf-read-data), they stated that :

> The scanf() function returns the number of fields that were successfully converted and assigned. The return value does not include fields that were read but not assigned.

which means like for example , if you have a code like that :

```
int x;
int numOfAssignedVars = scanf("%d", &x);
```

then if the user enter a valid number like **2** for example then the value of `numOfAssignedVars  = 1` but if the user entered a char like **s**
then `numOfAssignedVars  = 0` which indicated failure of the conversion

Answer (score 1):

This is a fabulous question.

The answer is: *You cannot force the user to give you good input.*
You can only detect it and complain (and quit).

*Getting* the input is the trick, then. In general, you should consider the following mantra:

→ ***Every time you ask for input, expect the user to press*** <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This makes life a little more predictable:

1. Get user input using `fgets()` (or `getline()` or any other reasonable function to get a newline-terminated string from the user).
2. Then try to convert the string to the type of object you desire. If it does not convert, then the user supplied bad input and you can complain and rage quit.

For example, suppose you want a floating-point value from the user:

```
printf( "What... is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow? " );
```

Get the input:

```
char s[100];
fgets( s, sizeof(s), stdin );
```

(Don’t forget to complain if the input is bad — in this case, if the answer doesn’t fit in 99 characters:)

```
char * nl = strpbrk( s, "\r\n" );
if (!nl) complain_and_quit();
*nl = '\0';
```

On to step two: attempt to convert the string to the proper type:

```
char * endp;
double speed = strtod( s, &endp );
```

If it didn’t work, user’s input is bad. Notice, in particular, how we check to see that the *entire* string was consumed:

```
if (*endp) complain_and_quit();
```

(You may want to add consideration for skipping trailing whitespace, which the user may enter as well.)

Otherwise all is good!

```
if (20.0 <= speed && speed <= 20.1)  // give user benefit of rounding off
  printf( "Good job!\n" );
else
  printf( "Correct answer is 20.1 mph\n" );
```

More complex inputs require a bit more vetting, but simply having a function to *transform* the input string to that type or fail is enough to proceed for any given input type.

As a final note, remember that some types may overlap. For example, an `int` is also a valid `double`. If you need to tell them apart, try the integer conversion first, as `3.14` will fail to convert correctly.

Oh, almost forgot: https://interestingengineering.com/science/monty-python-and-the-holy-grail-airspeed-velocity-of-an-unladen-swallow

Comment: _"you can complain and rage quit"_ -- That may be appropriate at times, but other times maybe it would be better to give the user at least a few chances to get input right before determining that the user is malicious, incompetent, or both.

Comment: It has nothing to do with judging the user as malicious and/or incompetent. It has everything to do with proper error handling. Unless you have written an interactive application with _any_ kind of UI, don’t assume you have a human present.

Comment: Apples and bananas. Totally different use case.

Comment: Oh @Dúthomhas -- I don't assume that there is a human present, but if there is they wouldn't be too happy about a program closing unceremoniously because they mistyped something. As I said before immediate closure _"may be appropriate at times, but other times maybe it would be better to give the user at least a few chances."_

Answer (score 0):

scanf is not great for input validation...
I would recommend to read input as a string in a buffer.
Then use strtol, strtoll, strtod or strtof on that buffer to parse the user input, depending on what you expect.
Those functions will tell you if there was an overflow, if there is no conversion possible or if there are characters in the buffer that were not converted.

Look [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof) for the man pages for those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code with scanf which allows to enter only an integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number;
    printf("Your number : ");
    while(scanf("%d", &number)!=1 || getchar()!='\n')
    {
        scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
        printf("You must enter an integer: ");
    }

    printf("%d\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A number in C can be an int, long long, double, float, short int ... etc. Depending on the precision you want.

I will suppose it's a double (since it contains all other types: int, short, float ... etc).

When using scanf(), according to [this link](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled

If you give it a string as an argument, the returned value will be 0. Since 0 float numbers have been detected.

```
int b = scanf("%d", &i); // b = 1 if given an integer, 0 if it is a string
```